# How to select dynamic checkboxes in Cypress based on a unique value of the same row?

Tags: javascript, automated-tests, cypress

In my application, there is a contact form. When executing the tests I will add a new contact and I need to select the checkbox based on that contact number uniquely. Because only the contact number is unique there.

[contact menu image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ocPu.png).

This is the checkbox element.

```
<input ref="eInput" class="ag-input-field-input ag-checkbox-input" type="checkbox" id="ag-229-input" aria-label="Press Space to toggle row selection (unchecked)" tabindex="-1" xpath="1">
```

I tried many ways to do it but I am stuck. Is there any possible way to approach this kind of situation?

Comment: @JanetSuzman No. But thanks for the reply. In my case there is no any table td.